# Implementar swipe na lib Venobox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera tô usando uma lib chamada venobox em um site, mas ele não tem nativo o swipe que é o deslize da imagem de lado para passar ela ou voltar e já tentei implementar a lib TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin mas não funciona nas imagens funciona na div mas não nas imagens, segue meu código:

```
<div id="hover-bg">
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="placas" href="fotos/fotos/10f218859743e9bc947c81570c1066f1.jpg" title="TEXTO DA IMAGEM">
        <div class="hover-text">
            <p class="lead">Placas
                <br />e Fachadas</p>
            <div class="hline"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="img/portfolio/01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
    </a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="placas" href="fotos/fotos/af62036784528f8773a96bd71b5557b3.jpg" title="TEXTO DA IMAGEM"></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="placas" href="fotos/fotos/cfd8447feaa62c6dcc6cbc1ec4426934.jpg" title="TEXTO DA IMAGEM"></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="placas" href="fotos/fotos/d6a7f824cf38c0a9d04493f394454300.jpg" title="TEXTO DA IMAGEM"></a>
    <a class="venobox" data-gall="placas" href="fotos/fotos/4d801e94fd84df663485178959bf6783.jpg" title="TEXTO DA IMAGEM"></a>
</div>


<script id='code_1'>
    // Aqui deve funcionar o swipe das imagens
    $("#hover-bg").swipe({
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            if (direction == "left") {
                // Preciso chamar o metodo de passar a foto
                // no arquivo galeria/js/venobox.min.js
                alert("Próxima foto");
            } else if (direction == "right") {
                // Preciso chamar o metodo de voltar a foto
                // no arquivo galeria/js/venobox.min.js
                alert("Foto Anterior");
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

alguem pode me ajudar??